# Using ng-repeat in md-autocomplete to display auto suggestion and popular products

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

I'm trying to use angular material `md-autocomplete` directive to display two different things one is popular products and other is auto suggestions but you can only use one `md-item` for iteration so i decided to use `ng-repeat`. I used three loops first one on a array that is returning from the `getSuggestion()` function which itself contains two arrays: an array of popular products objects and an array of suggestions object.
The problem is that now when I'm using up and down key to select an item it is selecting a list of item rather than an individual item and when i click on a particular item i get something like this `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[objct Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in my search box instead of an item string like i would get when i use `md-item` to iterate either over popular products or suggestions array.

My data is like this:

```
Object {popular_products: Array[3], suggestion: Array[0], cat_suggestion: Array[0]}
```

This is my code in controller:

```
$scope.getSuggestions = function(query) { 
    $scope.query = query;
    return $http.get(url + "?q=" + $scope.query + "&ssize=6&psize=3")
        .then(function(response) {
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
              console.log(response.data);
              //return $q.resolve(response.data)
              return $q.resolve([response.data.suggestion, response.data.popular_products]);
            } else {
                return $q.reject(response.data); // invalid response
        }, function(response) {
            return $q.reject(response.data); // Error
        });
```

};

This is my view:

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-no-cache="true"
    md-search-text= "query"
    md-items="sugg in getSuggestions(query)"
    md-item-text="sugg.suggestion"
    md-delay="0"
    md-min-length="1"
    placeholder="Search">
   <md-item-template>
        <div ng-if="$index == 0">
            <div ng-value="item.suggestion" ng-repeat="item in sugg">{{item.suggestion}}</div> 
        </div>
        <div ng-if="$index==1">
            <span>
                <b>Popular products:</b>
                <div ng-value="pp.price" ng-repeat="pp in sugg ">
                    {{pp.price}}
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

This is what happens when i hover over a suggestion it highlights a list of suggesitons rather than an individual suggestion:

[image]

which leads to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here I guess

```
return $q.resolve([response.data.suggestion, response.data.popular_products])
```

Try to

```
return $q.resolve(response.data.suggestion.concat(response.data.popular_products))
```

Because you have `[[],[]]` so it causes the problem